# Replace column values of specific set of rows with the previous values of the specific set

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have data in a SQL Server table like this:

| Entered Date | TypeName | TypeVal |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1/1/2021 10:25:24 | A1 | 13.4 |
| 1/1/2021 10:25:24 | B1 | 12.3 |
| 1/1/2021 10:25:24 | C1 | 15.2 |
| 1/1/2021 10:25:24 | D1 | 16.2 |
| 1/1/2021 10:25:24 | E1 | 0 |
| 1/1/2021 10:25:24 | F1 | 12.3 |
| 1/1/2021 10:25:24 | G1 | 1.2 |
| 1/1/2021 10:26:24 | A1 | 0 |
| 1/1/2021 10:26:24 | B1 | 0 |
| 1/1/2021 10:26:24 | C1 | 0 |
| 1/1/2021 10:26:24 | D1 | 0 |
| 1/1/2021 10:26:24 | E1 | 21.1 |
| 1/1/2021 10:26:24 | F1 | 3.4 |
| 1/1/2021 10:26:24 | G1 | 2.6 |
| 1/1/2021 10:27:24 | A1 | 43.1 |
| 1/1/2021 10:27:24 | B1 | 16.2 |
| 1/1/2021 10:27:24 | C1 | 18.9 |
| 1/1/2021 10:27:24 | D1 | 12.8 |
| 1/1/2021 10:27:24 | E1 | 1.8 |
| 1/1/2021 10:27:24 | F1 | 13.5 |
| 1/1/2021 10:27:24 | G1 | 14.8 |

I would like to check the condition that during a given datetime (`EnteredDate`) if `TypeVal` column contains ZEROs for TypeName (A1,B1,C1,D1 - all included) then all the values should be replaced from the previous `EnteredDate`'s `TypeVal`s for respective `TypeName`.

In the example above the expected result will be like

| Entered Date | TypeName | TypeVal |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1/1/2021 10:25:24 | A1 | 13.4 |
| 1/1/2021 10:25:24 | B1 | 12.3 |
| 1/1/2021 10:25:24 | C1 | 15.2 |
| 1/1/2021 10:25:24 | D1 | 16.2 |
| 1/1/2021 10:25:24 | E1 | 0 |
| 1/1/2021 10:25:24 | F1 | 12.3 |
| 1/1/2021 10:25:24 | G1 | 1.2 |
| 1/1/2021 10:26:24 | A1 | 13.4 |
| 1/1/2021 10:26:24 | B1 | 12.3 |
| 1/1/2021 10:26:24 | C1 | 15.2 |
| 1/1/2021 10:26:24 | D1 | 16.2 |
| 1/1/2021 10:26:24 | E1 | 0 |
| 1/1/2021 10:26:24 | F1 | 12.3 |
| 1/1/2021 10:26:24 | G1 | 1.2 |
| 1/1/2021 10:27:24 | A1 | 43.1 |
| 1/1/2021 10:27:24 | B1 | 16.2 |
| 1/1/2021 10:27:24 | C1 | 18.9 |
| 1/1/2021 10:27:24 | D1 | 12.8 |
| 1/1/2021 10:27:24 | E1 | 1.8 |
| 1/1/2021 10:27:24 | F1 | 13.5 |
| 1/1/2021 10:27:24 | G1 | 14.8 |

Where the 1/1/2021 10:26:24 TypeVals got replaced with the 1/1/2021 10:25:24 values.

Please advise.

**EDIT**
What I tried to achieve this

1. Tried using common table expressions like

;WITH cte
AS
(
Select  TypName, EnterredDate, sum(TypVal) valsum
from ResolTble
where TypName in ('A1','B1','C1')
group by TypName, EnterredDate
),
CTERanked
as
(
select TypName, EnterredDate, valsum, ROW_NUMBER() over(order by EnterredDate) rownum
from cte
)
select t1.EnterredDate, t1.TypName, t1.TypVal
from cteranked r1, ResolTble t1
where r1.EnterredDate = lag(r1.EnterredDate) over(order by r1.EnterredDate)

I am stuck at the where condition in the last select. I need to join the r1.EnterredDate with the t1.EnterredDate where the typval for the current typname is non zero, if the current typval is zero for the set of A1,B1,C1,D1. There can be more TypNames but the checking is only on the A1,B1,C1,D1. If these are zero then all the values in the current entered date should be from the previous non zero entered date for respective typnames.

Comment: What have **YOU** tried so far? Where are you stuck?

Comment: I have made a [DBFiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=7c4cb618679c2948252fd9920f158aa8) for you with your data. Please put here your attempt to achieve this there and post it in your question. Then we can easily help you

Answer (score 0):

If you want to skip the zero's in the `LAG` window function.
Then know that in some RDBMS you could ignore NULL's in a `LAG`.
But MS Sql Server doesn't support that.

However, it's possible to use an Gaps-And-Islands trick to emulate that.

The query below first calculates a ranking that ignores the zero's defaulted to NULL.

Then takes the maximum value by using that ranking.

> ```
> ;WITH CTE AS (
>   SELECT EnterredDate, TypName, TypVal
>   , RankTypVal = COUNT(NULLIF(TypVal, 0)) OVER (PARTITION BY TypName ORDER BY EnterredDate) 
>   FROM ResolTble
> ) 
> SELECT EnterredDate, TypName
> , TypVal = MAX(TypVal) OVER (PARTITION BY TypName, RankTypVal)
> FROM CTE
> ORDER BY EnterredDate, TypName;
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> EnterredDate            | TypName | TypVal
> :---------------------- | :------ | -----:
> 2021-01-01 10:25:00.000 | A1      |  13.40
> 2021-01-01 10:25:00.000 | B1      |  12.30
> 2021-01-01 10:25:00.000 | C1      |  15.20
> 2021-01-01 10:25:00.000 | D1      |  16.20
> 2021-01-01 10:25:00.000 | E1      |   0.00
> 2021-01-01 10:25:00.000 | F1      |  12.30
> 2021-01-01 10:25:00.000 | G1      |   1.20
> 2021-01-01 10:26:00.000 | A1      |  13.40
> 2021-01-01 10:26:00.000 | B1      |  12.30
> 2021-01-01 10:26:00.000 | C1      |  15.20
> 2021-01-01 10:26:00.000 | D1      |  16.20
> 2021-01-01 10:26:00.000 | E1      |  21.10
> 2021-01-01 10:26:00.000 | F1      |   3.40
> 2021-01-01 10:26:00.000 | G1      |   2.60
> 2021-01-01 10:27:00.000 | A1      |  43.10
> 2021-01-01 10:27:00.000 | B1      |  16.20
> 2021-01-01 10:27:00.000 | C1      |  18.90
> 2021-01-01 10:27:00.000 | D1      |  12.80
> 2021-01-01 10:27:00.000 | E1      |   1.80
> 2021-01-01 10:27:00.000 | F1      |  13.50
> 2021-01-01 10:27:00.000 | G1      |  14.80
> ```

Demo on *db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=7bcc1c2cb47d94b11ff394ea29c81de5)*